# Should i configure port forwarding on my router to forward to port 22 of sftp? Will is be secure?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Can i set port forwarding on my router? Will the connection be encrypted then?

Comment: Yes, you can forward any port. What is "opinion based" is the *Will it be secure?* part. Secure by what measure? By goverment standards or by a "I don't care" user? Secure using which protocols ssh or telnet? etc. No that is **not** a simple question (and less an answer) by any measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: *yes*. Read more about how ssh encryption works [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-the-ssh-encryption-and-connection-process).

However, I suggest that you read up on how to secure (harden) ssh to protect yourself against brute force attacks and whatnot.

Plus maybe set a limit on port 22 in a local firewall (I personally use `ufw` and consider it a good tool: http://man.he.net/man8/ufw), or use a tool like `fail2ban`.

Follow this link: https://is.gd/lk5mIs for a bunch of good advice.